# Purge Kafka topic with Confluent's .NET Client for Apache Kafka

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I use the Confluent Kafka [library](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) for `.NET` to publish and subscribe to Kafka topics. Was trying to find in their documentation if it is possible to purge the topic with their SDKs, but couldn't. So the question is: is it possible to purge Kafka topic from publisher **or** consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `IAdminClient` instance to remove topic(s). Here is the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.IAdminClient.html#methods) for the supported methods.

Example using Confluent.Kafka v1.0.0:

```
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Confluent.Kafka.Admin;

...

using (var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig { BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092" }).Build())
{
  try
  {
    adminClient.DeleteTopicsAsync(new string[] { "topic-to-delete" }).Wait();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
  }
}
```